# Dozer map one lavel class to class with nested classes like fields

Tags: java, dozer

I have sourcs class

```
public class A{
    private String f1;
    private String f2;
    private String f3;
    private String f4;
  }
```

And I have desination class B. B contains С class like field.

```
 public class B{
    private String f1;
    private String f2;
    private C c;
  }

  public class C{
    private String f3;
    private String f4;
  }
```

I need map A to B. I create mapperBuilder and config logic

```
BeanMappingBuilder mappingBuilder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {

      TypeMappingBuilder test = mapping(A.class, B.class);
      test .fields("f1", "f1");
      test .fields("f2", "f2");
      test .fields("f3", "???");
      test .fields("f4", "???");//How can I set f4 value to b.c.f4?
    }
  };
```

I create mapper:

```
  A a = new A();
  //add data to a object
  mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
  mapper.addMapping(mappingBuilder);
  B b= mapper.map(a, B.class);
```

Comment: `test.fields("f3", "c.f3")` maybe?

Comment: @ Lino do you think he will understand?

Comment: Who is *he*? Dozer? There's one way to find out. Try it